# Locating and recognizing text in vector drawings (DXF, SVG, WMF, etc.) without OCR?

Tags: text, graph-algorithm, vector-graphics

OCR doesn't work well on my content because a) it is in **vector format** from which raster images would need to be produced, and would be very, very large at the DPI required; and b)  the text is sparse (spread across large areas), doesn't appear in text lines, and often rotated or mirrored.  On the plus side, the text is almost always stroked using center-lines at a consistent size (or small handful of sizes).

It seems like this should be a similar problem to handwriting recognition, except that it operates on large coordinate spaces (i.e. not a single letter or word at a time) with huge amounts of non-character data in the drawing as well.

I have found very little research work on this kind of problem, and even less code.  Are there code libraries or algorithms that I should be looking at?

Comment: Ten years on, it looks like some progress is being made, albeit with AI rather than more traditional text recognition methods: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.03281.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I would use CadLib for DXF and DWG ([woutware.com](http://www.woutware.com))

Comment: It doesn't appear that CadLib will do this.  If there is documentation that indicates it will, I would love to see it.